# How to open link address containing HEX without converting HEX to digit?

Tags: c#, url, hex, uri, webrequest

I have links containing HEX values, I'm opening them with code below:

```
var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);

            try
            {
                 WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
                 webResponse.Close();
            }
```

But when WebRequest is created, links are converting to URI with loosing all special HEX values.
 For example:
original link:  /generic=http%3A%2F%2Fnym1.ib.adnxs.com%2Fab%3Fenc%3DRmeXLCKt4T
actual link:    /generic=http%3a/nym1.ib.adnxs.com/ab%3fenc%3drmexlckt4t

%2F was converted to /
Is it possible to force the opening of the original link, or maybe it is another way to open such links?

Thanks!